# Smart Home Actions for non-commercial project

Tags: actions-on-google

I created a free service that permits to control a French set-top box (which provides different services like TV, playing media, Netflix, …).

This set-top is a 3rd party product for me because I do not own the material, but because the constructor provides an API I've been able to create a service from end-to-end that controls the box. The box provider doesn't have any service published on Google to control their box and they do not plan to do it in the future.

I tested everything with my own Google Home account and everything is working fine. I'd now like to deploy/publish my service to all my users in Google Home… While I'm filling all the steps to publish my project, it's asking me to complete a form (**Smart Home Certification form**), but at the top of the form it says: *“if your action is non-commercial (personal/hobby project) or you are implementing only the SCENE trait, do not submit the form.”*

My action is non-commercial (it's a free service) and I'm maintaining it on my personal time (hobby project), so I'm not supposed to submit the form. But if I don't, then I cannot have my service published/deployed?!

**Is it possible to publish a Smart Home Action without being a company that sells products/pays a developer to maintain the service?**

For your information, I already published an Alexa Skill for this service 1 year ago and it works very well. I was waiting for Google to publish the Channel trait in French to release it. Right now I have to ask my users to create applets in IFTTT to make the service works with Google, which is not optimal and very painful…

I tried to reach to the *ha-certification* Google team but no answer after 2 weeks… So maybe someone in the community would already have experimented the same case as me!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After sending emails around, I finally got an answer from a Google employee:

> *due to our new policies, we are now not launching any partners who are not tied to commercial products*